# Automaticly backup image blog

Tags: mac, download, rss, automation, blogging

I have a image blog **at soup.io, similar to tumblr,** where I post images I find on the net for my friends. But I also would like to have a local copy of all the images on my mac to use as wallpapers etc. I would download them via hand, but it is to cumbersome as I sometimes several dozen pictures a day. Do you know any software or service, that could help me?

I tried [Automatic](http://codingcurious.com/automatic/) by Coding Curious, but it just stopped downloading after the first 'batch'. I contacted the programmer with the logs, but he couldn't help me. I also archive the blog in google reader which gets all images, but I don't know how to get them out of there.

Thank you

Nick

Comment: IMO, If the person who programmed the application could not help you, I would not trust the application.

Comment: You should give more specs: what platform do you use for blogging? do you have FTP or SSH access to the server hosting it? How do you insert pictures on the blog? Do they simply get put in a directory or there is a logic you must follow for the software to recognise them? What operating system is being used for your server? Etc...

Comment: the blog is hosted at soup.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that you could also ues Iphoto to download images from a RSS feed. The menue entry is called "Subscribe to Photo Feed”.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Httrack](http://httrack.darwinports.com/). You can easily filter by image types if you only want the images.